# Twitter api - trends/place

Tags: twitter

I have a question regarding the trends/place REST API of Twitter.
This API, according to Twitter "returns the top 50 trending topic for a specific WOEID, if trending information is available for it."
Thus it returns a list of trend topic dictionaries with the topic in the name field, all in json format
One of the fields returned in the response is the tweet_volume. My question is whether the tweet_volume represents the volume just for that WOEID, or whether this is the tweet volume across all of Twitter.

Here is a sample:

```
 [
  {
   "created_at": "2015-12-23T10:26:00Z", 
   "trends": [

    {
     "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Mesut+Ozil%22", 
     "query": "%22Mesut+Ozil%22", 
     "tweet_volume": 17195, 
     "name": "Mesut Ozil", 
     "promoted_content": null
    }, 
   "locations": [
   {
    "woeid": 23424863, 
    "name": "Kenya"
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tweet_volume` value is brand new addition to the API. You can learn about it on the [Twitter Developer forums](https://twittercommunity.com/t/more-than-10-results-in-trends-place-json-endpoint/57432/3):

> Additionally, we are also now returning a tweet_volume for each trend
>   - this is the volume of tweets per trend for the last 24 hours.

I believe that this is across the site rather than per WOEID but ICBW.

Comment: Thanks much. @AndyPiper